# Elastic search score discrepancy

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have only a single record in my elastic search cluster. It has the text "Foo Bar".

When I run the following query on the cluster, the `score` comes out to be `0.11506979` :

```
{
  "size" : 100,
  "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "foo bar"
        }
      } 

}
```

However, when I run the following query (notice the * after foo bar) on the cluster, the `score` comes out to be `0.9798734`

```
{
  "size" : 100,
  "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "foo bar*"
        }
      } 
}
```

Why is the score more in case I add the * ? Isn't there only one document to match?

Answer (score 1):

**Why is the score more in case I add the * ?**

The above * matches documents that have fields matching a wildcard expression (not analyzed). It matches any character sequence (including the empty one)

**Isn't there only one document to match?**

It depends on your index analyzer, how you are indexing your fields in a given document. If you are using default analyzer then ES will use a standard analyzer. To check exactly how your indexed data is getting stored internally in ES go through [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

Also, regarding the actual score you should be aware of internal mechanism which is used by ES for scoring docs. [This](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html) will help you getting a better idea of scoring mechanism.

In case of any doubts feel free to ask further questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use wildcards like * the scoring is done using ConstantScore strategy which takes only boost and queryNorm into account . Hence the score changes . pass the param `explain=true` to see how your score is being calculated.